# How to turn off webpack bundling changing class names for just 1 class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, webpack, bundler

I have a basic class in my code:

```
class MyClass1 {}
```

and I use webpack to compile the full code. After compilation all class names are changed by webpack to something like this:

> D_Documents_GitHub_Project_node_modules_babel_preset_react_app_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_classCallCheck__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"])(this,
> MyClass1);

For some reason I need a few classes in my entire code to keep their original name and not get renamed. What is the best way of achieving this ?

I know I can import them externally and use webpack-externals to prevent bundling, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with classes defined in the code itself, with maybe something like a decorator

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition)

```
exclude: {
  test: [
    ..,
    ..,
  ],
  exclude: [
    'src/configs/configs/some.extention'
  ]
}
```